# How to set location of a control dynamically in SSRS using the location property

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Hello everyone,
                I have a tablix of 4 columns and on some condition i show/hide the 3rd column. i have seperate text boxes to display the total of the column data at the end of each column. on hiding the 3rd column the 4th column takes the position of the 3rd column and the text box assigned for the 3rd column i make it hide in visibility. Now i have to move the 4th column's text box to the 3rd column's location. how to do this using Code in Report Properties. I read that i have to create an instance of the report in the Code section. But i am not able to create an instance of the report. The idea is if i create an instance of the report then i can write code like

Dim rp As New 'Myreport()'

rp.GrandTotal.Location.Left = 5

please can anyone help

Comment: A different approach could be to copy the textbox and have it in the appropriate position, and show/hide it with reverse logic (i.e. have this one show when the other one is hidden)

Comment: @lc. yeah i can do that... but this will be like a work around and adding a duplicate text box control.. this will be my last resort.